# php CPU usage problem

Tags: php, mysql, cpu

I'm using a php script that use alot of php and mysql queries installed in dedi with 4 cores and 16gb ram when i use the command top it shows that php consume 80% of CPU however using the command mpstat - ALL to find out usage per core it show different result 96% idle for every core

```
root@datax:~# top   
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
27629 root      20   0  287432  31336  18544 R  80.1  0.2   0:19.20 php
1006 mysql     20   0 2400692 100236  11340 S  21.3  0.6 220:35.64 mysqld



root@datax:~# mpstat -P ALL
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 (datax)    07/31/2016      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

05:03:13 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
05:03:13 AM  all    1.39    0.15    0.51    1.72    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.19
05:03:13 AM    0    1.31    0.15    0.47    1.73    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.31
05:03:13 AM    1    1.33    0.15    0.48    1.76    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.25
05:03:13 AM    2    1.49    0.15    0.55    1.68    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.10
05:03:13 AM    3    1.44    0.14    0.55    1.72    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.11
```

Answer (score 1):

The mpstat output is showing you the averages since boot (not "now") when you run it without an interval setting.  You can adjust your call to:

`root@datax:~# mpstat -P ALL 1`

this should provide you more of the 'now' information